# Selenium throwing a Null Point exception when using wait.until

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

public class UniversityTest {

```
WebDriver driver;
WebDriverWait wait;

@Before
public void preConditions()
{
    DriverUtilities myDriverUtilities = new DriverUtilities();
    driver = myDriverUtilities.getDriver();
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    driver.get(TestData.FDMUrl);
    Wait<WebDriver> wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, Duration.ofSeconds(2));
    
}  
 
@Test 
public void universityTest() throws IOException
{
    HomePage.ourWorkLink(driver);
    UniversityUsefulMethod.hoverFunction(driver, HomePage.ourWorkLink(driver));
    Assert.assertEquals(TestData.universities,HomePage.universityLink(driver).getText());
    
    HomePage.universityLink(driver).click();
    Assert.assertEquals(TestData.universityPageUrl,driver.getCurrentUrl()); 
    Assert.assertEquals(TestData.partnerships, UniversityPage.partnerships(driver).getText());
    Assert.assertEquals(TestData.recruit, UniversityPage.recruit(driver).getText());
    
    UniversityUsefulMethod.scrollFunctionDown(driver);
    UniversityPage.leftArrow(driver).click();
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"slick-slide06\"]/p")));






} 

@After
public void tearDown() {
    //driver.quit();
}
```

}

I'm trying to get selenium webdriver to wait until the element is located (via its xpath) but it returns a null point exception: this.wait is null.

Comment: wait is initialized in the scope of another method.  (because it's been typed strangely: Wait<WebDriver>...) Instead, do it right at the top there:  WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, Duration.ofSeconds(2));  Then you can use it in any method.  (or just do wait = new WebDriverWait... in the @before method...)